# Is it safe to flockfile() a FILE* that has been fclosed()ed on linux?

Tags: c, linux, thread-safety

Is code like this safe on linux, in the sense that 1) it can not crash and can not read free()ed memory and 2) the freopen()ed file shares the same lockcount as the fclose()ed file?

Thread 1:

```
flockfile(file);
freopen("name", a", file);
funlockfile(file);
```

Thread2:

```
flockfile(file);
fputs("stuff", file);
funlockfile(file);
```

Comment: I can't put in an answer, but I'd question it in any code review that came my way. If it is safe I'd want a comment in there directing me to the source that says it is safe.

Comment: @John3136 thanks anyway

Comment: Why do you need the fclose call there anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no safe operations on a closed `FILE*`. From [fclose(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose):

> ...any further access (including another call to fclose()) to the stream results in undefined behavior.

This is because `fclose` (may) free the object to which the file pointer points.

However, it is perfectly safe to lock the stream while `freopen`ing it as the lock is tied to the stream, not the underlying file. As a matter of fact, according to [flockfile(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/flockfile):

> The stdio functions are thread-safe.

Additionally, `freopen` is also marked "MT-safe" in [freopen(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen). Therefore, `freopen` must take the lock internally<sup>1</sup> to avoid closing the underlying the file descriptor while another thread is, for example, `freopen`ing it. Therefore, it must be safe to take it externally (the lock is reentrent).

Finally, you don't actually need those calls to `flockfile` as all file operations are already thread safe anyways.

---

<sup>1</sup>I've verified (by reading the source) that both glibc and openbsd's libc (also used on android) lock the stream internally when `freopen` is called.

The glibc `freopen` code opens with:

```
FILE*
freopen (filename, mode, fp)
     const char* filename;
     const char* mode;
     FILE* fp;
{
  FILE *result;
  CHECK_FILE (fp, NULL);
  if (!(fp->_flags & _IO_IS_FILEBUF))
    return NULL;
  _IO_acquire_lock (fp); // <-- This a macro that calls the private equivalent of flockfile and does some gcc cleanup magic.
```

And closes with:

```
  _IO_release_lock (fp);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question to clarify it by removing the fclose() and just leaving the freopen(). What do you think of that case.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have anything you can reference to support the safety of this?

Comment: @JohnCashew, unfortunately, I can't find any documents explicitly saying that it's safe to call `freopen` while holding the lock but it would be impossible to safely implement `freopen` any other way.